# Bash User Input Search For Who is On Server If Statement Error Too Many Arguments

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, grep, who

I am working on an assignment that requires me to accept user input to search for current users on the server and if the user input is online, I need to output the users name. If the user is not logged in I need to respond accordingly. I have been working on this code for days and can't seem to figure it out. I can search for the user but when it comes to comparing my user input variable string with the variable string holding the users name who is logged in I keep getting an error that says too many arguments. Please see my code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please enter the user name you would like to search: " userName
name=$(who | grep "${userName}" | awk '{print $1}');
if  [ [  $name == *"$userName"* ] ];
then
        echo $name
else
        printf "That user is not logged in.\n";
fi
```

Comment: Take a peek at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and look for some examples/tutorials on writing a conditional statement in shell. Say this one: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but the main problem is the bash `[[ ]]` construct can't have spaces in between the brackets.  It think's you're trying to do multiple `[` commands, which is the POSIX `test` command.  If you fix that it works, but if the user has multiple ttys open is will print their name once for every one.  If you want to use `grep`, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the user name you would like to search: " userName
if who | awk '{print $1}' | grep -wq "$userName"
then
  echo "$userName is logged in."
else
  echo "That user is not logged in.";
fi

exit
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked. Linux is so sensitive, I will definitely keep practicing on my formatting.

Comment: This page helped me a lot when learning Bash.  The rest of the site is a great reference, too.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls